# Custom Forms to upload images in Django

Tags: django

I am creating an educational application where there is a page for teacher to register a ask for students. The problem I wanted was a field where the teacher was able to enter text and image.

I've searched richtexts for django, but they only work in admin and the teacher does not have admin permission.

Is it possible to customize a form in django that sends text and images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

It allows you to have rich text editor with images on your custom form